# Regular expression to prevent comma separator if operand has decimal

Tags: javascript, regex

I found this regex function which add thousand comma separator for an arithmetic expression.

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

console.log(numberWithCommas("1000")); // ok
console.log(numberWithCommas("1000.03")); // ok
console.log(numberWithCommas("1000.03+2300")); // ok
console.log(numberWithCommas("1000.03+0.2300")); // not ok
```

But if the operand has decimal, I do not want to add any comma separator. How should I modify this regex accordingly?

p/s the math operator can be +,-,*,/

Comment: You probably mean to omit only commas *after* a decimal period, if so please clarify that.

Comment: yeah, I would like to omit commas after a decimal period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be using [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a callback function and match 1+ times a zero followed by a dot and zero.

If that is matched, return it in the replacement, else return a comma.

```
\b0+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)*|\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1JVchx/1)

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
  const regex = /\b0+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)*|\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g;
  return x.toString().replace(regex, (m) => m !== "" ? m : ",");
}

console.log(numberWithCommas("1000"));
console.log(numberWithCommas("1000.03"));
console.log(numberWithCommas("1000.03+2300"));
console.log(numberWithCommas("1000.03+0.2300"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `toLocaleString` for this pattern.

> The toLocaleString() method returns a string with a language-sensitive
>   representation of this number.

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    if (x.includes('+')) {
        return x.split('+').reduce((result, val) => {
            return result + (result == '' ? '' : '+') + Number(val).toLocaleString();
        }, '');
    } else {
        return Number(x).toLocaleString()
    }
}
```

```js
var regex = /[+\-\*\/]/g; 
function numberWithCommas(x) {
  if (regex.test(x)) {
    let sign = x.match(regex)[0];
    return x.split(sign).reduce((result, val) => {
      return result + (result == '' ? '' : sign) + Number(val).toLocaleString();
    }, '');
  } else {
    return Number(x).toLocaleString()
  }
}

console.log(numberWithCommas("1000"));
console.log(numberWithCommas("1000.03"));
console.log(numberWithCommas("1000.03+2300"));
console.log(numberWithCommas("1000.03-0.2300"));
```

Comment: But I need to format the whole expression , not just an operand.

Comment: Changed solution. Adding toLocaleString formatting for expression.

Comment: the math operator can be also +,-,*,/

Comment: @Steve use regex here to detect and split it. `regex = /[+\-\*\/]/g; regex.test(x)`

Comment: if "0." pass in, it will become 0. How to maintain it as "0."?